# Interrupted cron script sending me hourly emails. Please help!

Tags: email, cron, wp-cron

One of my Wordpress installs (cPanel VPS) had a cron job (backup to Dropbox script) that was interrupted. Ever since the interruption I receive hourly emails from root@ cPanel/WHM:
-Excessive resource usage
-Suspicious process running under user […]

The suspicious process emails include the following:
***Network connections by the process (if any):

tcp: 108.160.148.116:52480 -> 54.235.162.219:443***

That last IP address is a Dropbox IP. The thing is I have checked for any running jobs, have deactived and deleted the plugins responsible and have installed Cron checking plugins and no cron scripts are currently in place that have anything to do with the Dropbox backup. I have also checked in cPanel and no cron jobs are listed.

And yet I still receive the emails. Every hour. They are driving me crazy! But I don't just want to set up a rule in the email to delete them as I figure something must be going on to make cPanel/WHM send me these emails.

Does anyone have any suggestions, I'm desperate!

Comment: What this has to do with WordPress? Had you tried contacting hosting support about it?

Comment: Well Rarst, it's a Wordpress install and the cron scripts were generated by Wordpress backup plugins. Doesn't get much more Wordpress than that to me. And yes, I did contact hosting support about two weeks ago,.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it's worth, I found wp-cron processes running under the Processes section in WHM. I killed them and now all wp-cron behavior is back to normal and the emails have stopped.